# Computing an integral using Euler's substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to compute $$ \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-1}$$

Let's substitute $y=\sqrt{x^2-1} \implies y^2=x^2-1 = a(x-x_0)^2+\beta \implies x_0 = 0, \beta = -1$

$$t = y+\sqrt a(x-x_0) = y+x  $$

$$\frac{\beta}{t} = -\frac{1}{t} = y-x$$

Therefore $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{2} -\dfrac{1}{2t^2} \implies dx = \dfrac{1}{2}(1-\dfrac{1}{t^2})dt$

We now have

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-1} = \int \frac{\dfrac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2t^2}}{\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}-1}dt = \int \frac{t^2-1}{t(t-2t-1)}dt$$

We now have a rational function, I find that $\dfrac{t^2+1}{t(t-1)^2} = \dfrac{1}{t}+ \dfrac{2}{(t^2-2t-1)}$

Therefore $$\int \frac{t^2+1}{t(t-1)^2}dt = \int\frac{-1}{t} dt+  \int\frac{2}{t^2-2t-1}dt = \log(t) + \dfrac{1-t+\sqrt2+1)-log(t+\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt2} +C $$

If I switch back to the variable $x$,

$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-1} = \log(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x) +  \dfrac{log(1-\sqrt{x^2-1}+x+\sqrt2+1)-log(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x+\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt2} +C $

Wolframalpha makes me believe I'm wrong, could a courageous being tell me where the error is (or errors are).

The answer given by wolframalpha is:

\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{4}\left(4\log(\sqrt{x^2-1} +x\right) -2\sqrt{2} \tanh^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right) \\[8pt]
{} + {} & \sqrt{2} \log \left(\sqrt{2}-x-\sqrt{2} \log(x+\sqrt2) \right) +C
\end{align}

Thank You

Comment: It indeed does not look the same. You have one non-log term.

Comment: I think that $dx/dt=1/2+1/(2t^2)$ is wrong. It should be $dx/dt=1/2\color{red}{-}1/(2t^2)$.

Comment: @mickep One can write that  “non-$\log$” term in terms of $\log$, specifically, $$\tanh^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{\log(x+1)-\log(1-x)}2.$$

Comment: @mickep It's a typo, there should be an additional parenthesis: $\log(\sqrt{2}-x\color{red})$.

Comment: @mathlove indeed, it changes a lot of the calculations

Comment: @mickep Oh, that's right, didn't notice it!

Comment: I changed my post the thing is I don't know if the end part of my answer and of wolfram's answer ar the same, they're written under different forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in factorizing your denominator after substituting in for $t$.

You had:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2t^2}}{\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}-1}$$

You made a plus/minus mistake in the denominator. You should have gotten $t^2-2t-1$ rather that $t^2-2t+1$.

You had also made a plus/minus mistake in the numerator prior to this when you substituted in for $t$. You should have gotten $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2t^2}$ rather than $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2t^2}$

The expression should have become:

$$\int\frac{t^2-1}{t(t^2-2t-1)}\ dt$$

This would hence give you different partial fractions.

$$=\int \frac{1}{t}+\frac{2}{t^2-2t-1}\ dt$$

Comment: The numerator $1/2+1/(2t^2)$ is also wrong. see my comment above.

Comment: @mathlove yes i edited the post accordingly

Comment: @mathlove Yeh I noticed. Was just editing my post.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to substitute $x=\cosh\theta$ and get:
$$ I = \int\frac{\sinh\theta\,d\theta}{\sinh\theta-1} = \theta+\int\frac{d\theta}{\sinh\theta-1}$$
then through $\theta=\log u$:
$$ \int\frac{d\theta}{\sinh\theta-1}=\int\frac{2\,du}{u^2-2u-1}\\=\int\frac{2\,du}{(u-1)^2-2}=C+\frac{\log(1+\sqrt{2}-u)-\log(-1+\sqrt{2}+u)}{\sqrt{2}}.$$